# List only Oracle Temp Table Space

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, tablespace

Is there way to list only temp tablespaces in Oracle? I found following query which is listing all the tablespaces, I just need only temp tablespaces.

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can filter the list by the `contents` column:

```
SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces WHERE contents = 'TEMPORARY'
```

As described in the Oracle Database Online Documentation for [`dba_tablespaces`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5054.htm).

Comment: Thanks it worked. SQL> SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces WHERE contents = 'TEMPORARY';

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
TEMP
TEMPRM

Answer (score 1):

You can the dba_temp_files, that has tablespace_name column

```
select distinct (TABLESPACE_NAME) from dba_temp_files;
```